# observablecollection to dataView or dataset

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid, observablecollection

I have a Datagrid formed by binding observablecollection, Now i want to provide Export to excel Functiom, So i need to Convert by datagrid to dataset or dataview.

```
public ObservableCollection<DataSourceVM> Backends { get; set; }
private void StartExport(String filepath)
   {
       try
     {
      DataTable bs = _dataGrid.ItemsSource as DataTable;
      _dataSet = bs.DataSet as DataSet;

   }
   catch (Exception e1)
  {
     MessageBox.Show("error");
  }
}
```

The ItemSource Contains a baseclass and Backend entity class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create the datatable by hand with the columns you need. I assume that the columns are the properties of DataSourceVM class.

```
public ObservableCollection<DataSourceVM> Backends { get; set; }

private void StartExport(String filepath)
{
    try
    {
        var dataSet = new DataSet();
        var dataTable = new DataTable();
        dataSet.Tables.Add(dataTable);

        // we assume that the properties of DataSourceVM are the columns of the table
        // you can also provide the type via the second parameter
        dataTable.Columns.Add("Property1");
        dataTable.Columns.Add("Property2");

        foreach (var element in Backends)
        {
            var newRow = dataTable.NewRow();

            // fill the properties into the cells
            newRow["Property1"] = element.Property1;
            newRow["Property2"] = element.Property2;

            dataTable.Rows.Add(newRow);
        }

        // Do excel export
    }
    catch (Exception e1)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("error");
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply It worked. One more question if my datagrid in view is binded to observablecollection, Can i Convert that datagrid to dataset, I am able to pass that datagrid object to viewmodel but not able to convert

Comment: It is the other way around. Your collection is bound to the datagrid as an ItemsSource. You do not need to interact with the datagrid directly. In regual cases you should not pass UI controls to viewmodels. Work on the data object you provide to the UI like your collection.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it generically without knowing the type. I added the Attribute `ExcelExportAttribute`, so only properties with this Attribute are selected. You can remove the where-clause if you want all properties of the generic type.

```
    public static DataTable ToDataTable<T>(this IEnumerable<T> rows)
    {
        var result = new DataTable();
        // get generic properties that are marked with ExcelExportAttribute
        var propertyList = typeof(T).GetProperties().Where(prop => Attribute.IsDefined(prop, typeof(ExcelExportAttribute))).ToList();
        // add generic columns
        foreach (var tProperty in propertyList)
        {
            result.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(tProperty.Name, Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(tProperty.PropertyType) ?? tProperty.PropertyType));
        }
        // add all rows to datatable
        foreach (var row in rows)
        {
            var dataRow = result.NewRow();
            // fill all columns of current row
            foreach (var tProperty in propertyList)
            {
                var type = (Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(tProperty.PropertyType));
                var defaultValue = type?.IsValueType == true ? Activator.CreateInstance(type) : default(T);
                dataRow[tProperty.Name] = typeof(T).GetProperty(tProperty.Name).GetValue(row) ?? defaultValue;
            }
            result.Rows.Add(dataRow);
        }
        return result;
    }
```